# 'make clean' not working

Tags: makefile, mingw, msys

so I made a makefile for a c program. For some reason my 'clean' is not working. Here's a little bit of my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
FLAGS=-c -Wall -I.
CLEANC=rm -rf *.o

move.o: move.c
     $(CC) $(FLAGS) move.c
/*Lot more codes like this^^^*/

clean:
    $(CLEANC)
```

When I run 'make clean' in command prompt, I'm shown the following:

```
rm -rf *.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf *.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile:116: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried changing CLEANC to

```
rm -f *.o
rm *.o 
rm *o
rm -f *.o test.exe //test.exe is executable
```

but it still gave me the same error no matter what I tried. I could really use the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Your Makefile works perfectly with GNU Make 3.81 and GNU Make 4.2.1.

Comment: What OS? What happens when you try `rm -f *.o` on the command line?

Comment: It's giving me the same error. I am using Windows 10 with MinGW and MSYS installed. 'make' and 'make compile' works perfectly but for some reason 'make clean' always gives me that same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging from the `CreateProcess` appearing in your error output I assume you are running `make` under Windows.

This means that there is no `rm` command, you should use `del` instead and `-rf` flags should also be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I think the equivalent for Windows is `del /Q /S *.o` , presuming the object files end up as `.o` (i.e., mingw GCC) and not `.obj` (visual studio)

Comment: Thank you! Both answers worked! I assumed that `rm` command would work since `make` worked perfectly fine.

Comment: If you still want to use `rm` command in windows, I recommend you to take a look at cygwin (just google for it)

Comment: why can I not use rm, although rm is available in the console (powershell)?

Comment: @JFFIGK because `mingw32-make` uses `cmd` instead of `powershell`

Comment: Now, instead of `cygwin` I would recommend `msys2`

Answer (score 0):

```makefile
OBJS   = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS))))
DELOBJS = $(addprefix .\obj\,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS))))

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    del xxx 
    del $(DELOBJS)
```

`del` does not work because Windows uses `\` to distinguish file paths,so you have to take `OBJS` with `\path`, that is, `DELOBJS` I wrote