# make clean failed in windows

Tags: c, makefile, mingw

I want to use mingw to compile my C language project.

I found the command of `make all` succeeded, however `make clean` failed.  There are only two files in my test project: `test.c` and `Makefile.mak`.

`test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

`Makefile.mak`:

```
all: test.o
    gcc test.o -o test.exe

test.o: test.c
    gcc -c test.c

clean:
    @echo "clean project"
    -rm test *.o
    @echo "clean completed"
.PHONY: clean
```

When I ran `make all -f Makefile.mak`, it succeeded and generated the expected `test.exe`, and I also can run the executable. However, when I run `make clean -f Makefile.mak`, it failed, the error is:

```
"clean project"
rm test *.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm test *.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2):
Makefile.mak:8: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: [clean] Error 2 (ignored)
"clean completed"
```

[image]

Why?

**EDIT:**

The following link enlightened me:
[MinGW makefile with or without MSYS (del vs rm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928965/mingw-makefile-with-or-without-msys-del-vs-rm)

1. I added the workaround code mentioned in the above link in my `makefile`:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT) 
RM = del /Q /F
CP = copy /Y
ifdef ComSpec
SHELL := $(ComSpec)
endif
ifdef COMSPEC
SHELL := $(COMSPEC)
endif
else
RM = rm -rf
CP = cp -f
endif

all: test.o
    gcc test.o -o test.exe

test.o: test.c
    gcc -c test.c

clean:
    @echo "clean project"
    -$(RM) test.exe *.o
    @echo "clean completed"
.PHONY: clean
```

It works:

```
"clean project"
del /Q /F test.exe *.o
"clean completed"
```

2. This reminds me that it may be because current environment doesn't support `rm` command, so I add my `msys` install path into environment path, then it works:

```
clean project
rm test.exe *.o
clean completed
```

Comment: I don't think mingw has the `rm` command, but i could be wrong. `cygwin` is POSIX, and has rm

Comment: I would recommend that, If you find the answer to your own question, instead of extending the question with the answer incorporated, Answer your own question as a seperate answer.

Comment: Add a line `SHELL=cmd`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474485/error-with-makefile-in-c-on-clean-file-not-found

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

['make clean' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735464/make-clean-not-working)

Clean in MinGW by default will run -rm command. But this command is not supported by window. Window use del.

So you need to edit makefile with notepad++, change

```
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)
```

To

```
clean:
    -del -fR $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove a file called "test" but no such file exists.  As a result, the `rm` command fails.

You want to delete "test.exe", as that is the name of your output file.  Also,  you should use the `-f` option to `rm`, as that will 1) do a forced remove, and 2) won't fail if the file doesn't exist:

```
clean:
    @echo "clean project"
    -rm -f test.exe *.o
    @echo "clean completed"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed the makefile as your suggestion, but it still failed...