# error with makefile in c++ on clean, file not found

Tags: c++, powershell, makefile

Just starting out with c++ on Windows, I has a fresh install of WinGW just minutes ago and made sure to add it to path and all of that.

I'm using the following Makefile

```
main.exe: main.o
    g++ main.o -o main.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o, main.exe
```

when I run (doing this with powershell, not sure if it would make any difference) `make` it's fine, it runs exactly as it should, but when i run `make clean` I get this error:

> ```
> rm main.o, main.exe
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm main.o, main.exe, ...) failed.
> make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
> Makefile:10: recipe for target 'clean' failed
> make: *** [clean] Error 2
> ```

I'm unsure what's wrong, I tried escaping the asterisk (powershell still runs it if I run the individual line tho), I tried adding `SHELL=CMD`, and reinstalling the whole thing. I saw quite a few questions that are very similar, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Please Help.

EDIT: from the error I'm getting I'm guessing it has to to with the comma (,)? I tried surrounding everything in a string and commenting the comma, none gave results tho.

EDIT2: also tried deleting only `main.exe` but I get the same exact error

Comment: Remove the comma (`,`) from the `rm` command line.  Command-line arguments are whitespace delimited, not comma delimited.

Comment: @JohnBollinger actually, in powershell they are https://www.windows-commandline.com/powershell-delete-files/

Comment: Looks like `make` assumes you only pass binary executables, might have to change the `clean` command to `cmd /c del *.o main.exe`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that works, but why does `make` assume that?

Comment: Is MinGW's `rm` *not* a binary executable?  I would find that surprising.  If the problem is associated with `rm` as opposed to with the argument list, then the most likely explanation is that you are mistaken about it being in the path, at least in the window where you are running `make`.

Comment: make originated with UNIX/POSIX.  Running make on Windows means understanding a lot about your environment because there are so many options.  Is make running command.com?  Is it running powershell?  Is it running a POSIX shell?  Are the commands you run POSIX commands like *rm* or DOS commands like *del*?  Etc.  First, make never uses powershell unless you specifically tell it to, so you should ignore all knowledge of how things work in powershell.  Second, if you use POSIX commands like *rm* (and they exist) you have to follow their command line model, not Windows'.

Comment: @MadScientist I assumed that it actually ran `Remove-Item` which has an alias of `rm` https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/powershell-cheat-sheet/

Comment: MinGW predates PowerShell, would be weird if it defaulted to PowerShell as its command processor. Did you try rebooting your machine after installing MinGW? Could be that some env var updates are required to resolve `rm`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So I should assume runs linux commands instead of powershell commands? But I ran it without a comma before exactly because I assumed it wasn't comma delimited and i has the same error?

Comment: No, you should assume that `make` can only launch _executable programs_ - MinGW should include an `rm.exe` binary that you can use on Windows in lieu of a built-in `rm` program, which is what @JohnBollinger is talking about above. If `make` can't figure out where `rm.exe` executable is located (resulting in the error you see), it might indicate that something went wrong during the installation of MinGW (or perhaps you unchecked some options?) - or maybe you just need to reboot to complete the installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `rm *.o, main.exe` use `del *.o main.exe`

Thank you @JohnBollinger and @MathiasR.Jessen for the help in the comments.

For commands in `Makefile` use `cmd` commands and executables only :)

Comment: You should use either (a) command.com (cmd) commands, or (b) POSIX (MinGW) commands.  You cannot use powershell commands.  Make doesn't invoke powershell.  Which of (a) or (b) above depends on whether your make program invokes command.com or invokes a POSIX shell.  Typically, a MinGW environment will use a POSIX shell and POSIX commands.  But if make can't find the shell it will fall back to command.com (I think...)